# iOS 13 performActionFor shortcutItem doesn't get called in SceneDelegate now on launch, but does after app launches. Why?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios13, uiscene, uiscenedelegate

`performActionFor shortcutItem` gets called in my SceneDelegate if the app has already launched, but it doesn't get called if the app actually launches from a shortcut item. Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the ShortcutItems from willConnectTo  function in sceneDelegate when the app is launched from shortcut item (and when there is no instance of app is in background)

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
if let shortcutItems = connectionOptions.shortcutItem{
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, is this all there is to it? I have quick actions set up and working when the app is running via func windowScene(.. performActionFor shortcutItem..), but since that doesn't work when the app isn't launched, I was looking for a way to fix it. And I can't seem to get what you suggested to work. I added         if let shortcutItems = connectionOptions.shortcutItem{
            UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.alert(title: shortcutItems.debugDescription)
        } or tried saving the value to user defaults to test it and it does nothing. Any clues?